# Fast cloud backup solution with encryption and the ability to add ingorelists

Tags: cloud-storage

Working with multiple endpoints and devices I have a need for a new cloud based backup and device collaboration tool.
Like Dropbox, only more secure and with more functionality.
Right now I'm using sync.com
But they don't fit my needs anymore and are really really slow in updating.

So what I need is a tool that has the following specs

**Must-haves**

- End-To-End encryption and server-side encryption
- Fast syncing
- Needs to run on Windows and Debian
- Should be able to handle ingorelists, for example: always ignore folders
  with "node-modules" or similiar

**Nice-to-Have**

- The ability to run on a Synology NAS

Kind regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everyone in need of similar specs, I found [Koofr](https://www.koofr.eu/)! .

They have all I needed:

- End to End encryption ✅ (No zero-knowledge though)
- Syncs really fast on multiple devices ✅ (tested 1 Win 10 PC, 2 Debian Laptops, 1 Synology NAS, 2 Android Devices)
- Runs on All OS ✅ (Win, OSX, Linux)
- Has the ability to create [ingorelists](https://koofr.eu/blog/posts/advanced-ways-to-exclude-files-from-sync) ✅
- WebDAV to run on any kind of OS supporting this, including most common NAS ✅

*The pricing is totally fine, but nothing for bargaining folks, but it is worth the complexity and speed*.